# Setting htaccess parameters from PHP code

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have several files in a directory that require different types of authentication. For authentication we use [cosign](http://cosign.sourceforge.net/) which means we have to define the user groups or users that have access to a directory in an .htaccess file. Is there a way that in my PHP code I can define different rules? I need to set a rule like `Require user bjensen`. If not, is there a way in the .htaccess file that I can set certain parameters globally to all the pages and then specify rules for individual pages?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are application variables. I'm not sure how to answer the first part of your question, but "is there a way in the .htaccess file that I can set certain parameters..." can be done with SetEnv.

For example, in your .htaccess file for a particular directory you could specify that it has accesss to a certain security group by

```
SetEnv SECURITY_GROUP alpha
```

Then, in your PHP file, use

```
apache_getenv('SECURITY_GROUP')
```

and only show content if your user is in the "alpha" group. Does that get you closer to what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't quite what I was looking for. What I mean by setting certain parameters was defining certain rules that would apply to all the files in the directory like a normal htaccess and then have additional rules in the same htaccess file that were limited to specified files. Thanks for trying to help though.